# centering image overlaying another with xray effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

The issue I’m having here is with the x-ray image behind the one in the front. They do not line up. It only does when i stretch the browser out to 1920px. Anything smaller than that causes it to misalign. Note that I purposely set the image to be at 100% width which I know is not responsive. 
I want to keep the effect of the image getting cut off on the right and left of the browser. Ideally I'd like both images to be centered and aligned when I decrease the size of the browser.

Here is the Github link:
https://gist.github.com/siravani/71b8d447acaca8b34acfcab82af58c06

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you added a fiddle that would have been a lot easier but all you need to do is add background-size:cover to #flesh css rule

```
html, body, #flesh {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: url("http://www2.yapstone.com/l/109192/2017-04-04/4c61s2/109192/37539/buildings.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

this way your background image will fit in container and will match with the original image.

Here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w2jjaLn5/

Comment: Sorry, that's what I should have done. This is working great. But is there a way to maintain the width and keep it from shrinking when the window is resized? So essentially what I would like is to shrink the screen and have the image cut off on the right and left sides. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: yeah you can do it by assigning the main image as background image and  set background-size: cover; and set 100% width to your container div. this way they will be centered but fill the container. and when you resize container they will remain at same position, https://jsfiddle.net/v55tp9kf/

Comment: note that I separated html,body from flesh and moved img to background-image.

Comment: The images don't show up. If I remove the background-size: contain; the image in the front loads but it loses the masking feature.

Comment: Ok, for some reason jsfiddle didn't save my updates. take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/yf3u204x/ now.

Comment: Yes, it works, you're a life save. Appreciate it, thanks!